# Valid anagrams code - fails for one case out of 32 cases. passes for 31 cases

Tags: java, string, anagram

I tried writing a small code for anagrams and I wrote the below onw.

```
String s = "anagram";
String t = "nagara";
    
Map<Character,Integer> map1 = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
Map<Character,Integer> map2 = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
    
if (s.length() != t.length()) {
    System.out.println("Not an anagram");
} else {
    for (int i= 0;i<s.length();i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        char d = t.charAt(i);
        if (map1.containsKey(c)) {
            map1.put(c, map1.get(c)+1);
        } else {
            map1.put(c,1);
        }
            
        if (map2.containsKey(d)) {
            map2.put(d, map2.get(d)+1);
        } else {
            map2.put(d,1);
        }
    }
        
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
        if (!map2.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
            System.out.println("Not an anagram");
        } else if (entry.getValue() != map2.get(entry.getKey())) {
            System.out.println("Not an anagram");
        }
    }
}
```

This works for almost all casesto check, it fails for one of the longest anagrams with 50000 characters .
Would anyone be able to point me on what looks wrong here?

Comment: `entry.getValue() != map2.get(entry.getKey())` will test Integer object identity. Try with `!entry.getValue().equals(map2.get(entry.getKey()))`. Not sure if this will answer your question because I can't try your test cases.

Comment: What exactly is failing? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes. That works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

You are a victim of the [`Integer` caching](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-) for values between -128 and +127.

As you are counting the numbers of characters in both words, putting the value as a *boxed* `Integer` object into the map, you need to compare them as *objects*, not as *values*.

The problem is this line:

```
else if (entry.getValue() != map2.get(entry.getKey()))
```

Here you compare two `Integer` objects with `!=` instead of using

```
else if (!entry.getValue().equals(map2.get(entry.getKey())))
```

The reason why this works for short words is that the occurrence number of each character does not exceed the magical value of 127.

These values are cached in the `Integer` class, so that boxed integers less than (and equal to) that value are the *same* whereas boxed integers greater than that value are different objects with *equal* value.